Routing rules for xray not working with domain regexp or indicated directly
I use a server with an installed XRay proxy.
The problem is that I want to configure it so that the proxy is not used for certain domains or for a domain mask. But for some reason it does not work.
If you configure it through NekoBox, then everything is ok, but I want to configure it on the server so that I do not have to configure it on different clients each time. But it does not work.
What am I doing wrong?
Here is an example on the site https://ifconfig.me/
IP Address  185.255.111.111
But this is proxy IP.
I change config here: /usr/local/etc/xray/config.json
Routing settings:
"routing": {
    "rules":[
      {
        "type": "field",
        "ip": [
          "geoip:private",
          "geoip:ru"
        ],
        "domain": [
          "domain:vk.com",
          "domain:ifconfig.me",
          "ifconfig.me",
          "regexp:\\.ru$"
        ],
        "outboundTag": "direct"
      }
    ],
    "domainStrategy": "IPIfNonMatch"
  }


I've recently ran into similar issue.
First, according to documentation, when multiple attributes are specified at the same time, these attributes need to be satisfied simultaneously in order for the current rule to take effect.
Second, please take a look at outbounds and tags in your config file.
Here is an example:
{
  "outbounds": [
    {
      "tag": "proxy-out-vless"
      // ... ...
    },
    {
      "tag": "block",
      "protocol": "blackhole"
    },
    {
      "tag": "direct-out",
      "protocol": "freedom"
    }
  ]
}

Your rule's outboundTag should match one of those. In this example if you want to block access, then outboundTag should have value block
Third, it will take effect only on server, however this setting won't be automatically propagated to clients. In this case if there is no additional routing settings on a client, then traffic to the resources will be blocked. It's essential to add routing rules on client also, however this setting will prevent server exposure to censors if there are no routing rules on a client.
